# How to check if a batch running in a java code?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I think it's possible to check if a batch is running in the core of a java code.
But I don't know how.

And it's possible to check without the `pid` number of the batch?

Comment: which batch ? You mean messages in weblogic queue ?

Comment: we have developped some batch in my work and it is one of their. Currently, I have no message, I just know than I can check if a specific batch is running to continue my steps, if not, I can launch the specific batch before continue

Answer (score 0):

You need to make batch status available to query programmatically.  Some options include:

- write an entry to a log file or database on start & completion of each subtask in the batch
- update a progress / status entry in a database on completion of each subtask
- update a progress / status entry in an in-memory field and make available via JMX